# I would to "reload" an enum instance

Tags: enums, instance, reload, bukkit

I'm doing a plugin with Spigot (Minecraft) and I use enums to store messages/languages and also status of specific thing.
The problem is that status enum depends of message enum. And message enum depends of a file messages.yml.
I know how to reload that file but when I do it, messages sent are updated if I change translations in the file messages.yml but messages of status that are stored in status enum are not updated.

Therefore, I would want to know if it's possible to **remove instance of an enum and generate it again** to **update them values** like it does when the plugin is reloaded.

```js
public enum Message {

WAITING("Status.Waiting");

private String path;

Message(String path) {
this.path = path;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return file.getString(path);
}

}

public enum Status {

WAITING(Message.WAITING.getMessage());

private String name;

Status(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public getName() {
return name;
}

}
```

Please don't answer that I can put WAITING(Message.WAITING) and do Status.WAITING.getName() that would do name.getMessage();. I writted this code as an example, my functions don't use a getName() function, just the value of the enum so the name written in message enum.

Thanks in advance if anybody solve this. :)

Comment: why do you actually need to use enums? You could use a class with getters for all the messages, that would find them in your config and store in a map, for example

Comment: While `enums` may sound like a great idea for storing messages - it's really not. Enums are not designed to be reloaded, they're designed to be constants, so any hacks you put together will just not be worth the effort. What I recommend is just getting the message from the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add/remove to an `enum` because the `enum` is referenced in other code. This would be the same as removing all traces of a variable `foo` then trying to call `foo + 1`

If you want to reload the messages file, you can do file.reloadConfig() which will reload the messages from disk, and then any time you call getMessage() it will look for the newer message in the newer file.

Comment: I don't want to modify a value of the enum but reload the enum class. Like removing the place where it is stocked and generate it again.
Them values change on reload of the plugin (if file is modified) so I think it's possible to force that reload only for an enum or all the plugin also. I already tested various ways to reload my plugin but enums kept them values but changed when I restarted him with plugman plugin.